# Video monetising and simple shop, platform?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, video

I have this client that wants a single-product website.

The product is a training-video that they want to deliver virtually and optionally physically.

I usually do all the front-end design and back-end development but the budget is close to $0 to start with.

So I'm looking for a platform like shopify or something where a shop/cart can be set up quickly and simply with minimal up-front cost - but which can accomodate some kind of paywall (DRM too?) for the online video with an option to purchase for an aditional cost the physical DVD.

Am I approaching the wrong way all together? Or do you know of any platform that will accomodate the specs?

Answer (score 0):

I know that Magento Commerce can do both of the things that you require, and there are some nice looking templates that would be simple to modify for your needs. The downside is that  it is a rather heavy duty shopping cart software with tons of options, and has a slight learning curve getting it setup.

The community edition would work fine, but you would obviously need a place to host it. It uses PHP and MySQL so finding a host should not be tough, and I'm sure there are specialized Magento hosts for low monthly costs.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/community-edition